# Andrew's House Cleaning - A Word Ladder

Tags: wordplay, word-ladder

Andrew is cleaning his house but needs help. Your task is to get from **bits** to **bobs** to **odds** to **ends**. You can alter letters, one at a time, and each intermediate word must be a valid word in dictionary.com. You may not rearrange letters or make two words: ie. office->off ice. You may not use a program or online solver. Andrew has a guest coming to his house soon, so you need to do this as fast as possible (least number of steps).

P.S: Is this considered off-topic? I have the minimal solution in mind. Please let me know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To improve on the previous answer,

> **bits** bots **bobs** <strike>bods bids aids adds</strike> **odds** adds ands **ends**
>  **bits** bots **bobs** [bubs](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/bubs?s=t) [buds](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/bud?s=t) [ouds](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/oud) **odds** adds ands **ends**
>
>  Which places the minimal number of steps at 9.

Comment: Nice job! Also, can you explain how you got to this answer?

Comment: @Gareth McCaughan did the majority of the work; improving on bobs > odds was just a bit of trial and error on dictionary.com. I hope that's not what you meant by online solver.

Comment: No, that's not what I meant. +1 :-)

Comment: Ah, nice. Well done.

Answer (score 5):

I can do it in

> 10 steps

as follows:

> bits bots bobs bods bids aids adds odds adds ands ends

This *feels* about as good as should be possible, but maybe one can do better?

Comment: Very close, but not minimal.